# If the dimension of the null space of $T,S$ is $5$ and $3$ . What is the dimension of the null space of $T\circ S$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be a vector space with $\dim V =12$. Then $T$ and $S$ are linear operators on $V$.
>
> We have that the dimension of the null space of $T$ is $5$ and the dimension of the null space of $S$ is 3.
>
> Then what is the dimension of the null space of $T\circ S$?

I have found a post here [Dimension of Range and Null Space of Composition of Two Linear Maps](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1899164/dimension-of-range-and-null-space-of-composition-of-two-linear-maps)

By this post, I found that $\dim null(T\circ S)\leq \dim null(T)+\dim null(S)=5+3=8$.

Also $\dim range(T\circ S)\leq \min\{\dim range(T),\dim range(S)\}=\min\{7,9\}=7$

Hence $5\leq\dim null(T \circ S)\leq8$.

Is this correct?

Comment: This is correct.